# how to checked multiple check box through php

Tags: php, checkbox, checked

I am unable to checked multiple check box in php. I am getting a cinema seat data from API in comma separated form like A1,A2 . Now I have a seat map in which I have to checked those check boxes.
My code for seat values after getting from API is below.

```
<?php
list($a,$b) = explode(',',$seatvalue); //separating seat data in two vars
            $$a="checked";
            $$b="checked"
?>
```

Now in the form I have to check both check boxes so I am echo both variables like this.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|1' id="A2"  <?php echo  $A2; ?> /><label for="A2">A2</label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|0' id="A1"  <?php echo $A1; ?> /><label for="A1">A1</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

but my problem is only one check box is checked and not both.

Comment: What is the variable $A1?

Comment: @CoderDuse  $$a or  $$b will be $A1 and $A2 return by API values.

Comment: Which checkbox is checked?

Comment: Please post the result of `var_dump($seatvalue);`